# Does changing the android:label of my application require users to reinstall the app?

Tags: android, android-install-apk

I recently deployed an android app to the play store.  The client noticed that the app's title was not correct in the app list so I ended up changing it by modifying the `android:label` in both the `application` node as well as the `activity` node for the launcher activity.  My question is, should the client have to re-install the app or not?  I can't seem to find a concrete answer to this and they claim they had to re-install the app in order to get the icon title to update.  Simply updating the app through the Google Play store did not fix the issue.

EDIT TO CLARIFY:

I am not referring to the store listing.  I am referring to the title just below the app icon when viewing the list of apps installed on the phone.  The customer is claiming that performing an update through the Google Play store did not fix this, but uninstalling and reinstalling the application manually did.

Comment: Yes, they have to reinstall

Comment: Do you have evidence for this through documentation or just personal experience?

Comment: Are you referring to the title in the store listing?

Comment: @FarbodSalamat-Zadeh no, I'm referring to the title that is displayed just below the app icon in the list of apps on the phone.

Comment: Uploading a new APK to Google Play only changes what Google Play has. Every device that downloaded your app has whatever APK they got at install time. Unless they have Google Play set to automatically update apps, they will not have the new APK until they download and install it themselves. This is just like any other piece of software that ever existed.

Comment: @Karakuri there is a difference between an uninstall/re-install and an update...  Updates can happen automatically, (which the client has turned on).  The update did not work, they had to manually uninstall the application and re-install it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is, should the client have to re-install the app or not?

Any change you made to the app requires installation of new build for users too see the change on their devices, but there's no need to **reinstall** (uninstall and fresh install) and ordinary **upgrade** (so app data remains unaffected) perfectly suffices.

**EDIT**

> > *"But there's no need to full reinstall (uninstall and fresh install)"*
>
> this is what the client is claiming they had to do

There's insufficient information and my experience tells that customers often  claim nonsenses (or they simply do not understand the difference between upgrade/reinstall), still there's also a chance Launcher your user uses is buggy or somehow affected (i.e. I just spotted possible bug with quite popular Nova, that is also  not showing one app label correctly). IMHO there's nothing you should bother here.

Comment: `"But there's no need to full reinstall (uninstall and fresh install)"` this is what the client is claiming they had to do.  I edited the answer to clarify.

Comment: You _can_ reinstall, but you don't have to since you can just update.

Comment: Just tested and confirmed through TestFairy that the title changed when I updated a dummy app.  This is similar to our test case when we went live.  I will investigate and see if they are using some kind of custom app launcher.

Answer (score 0):

You users will either have to reinstall or update. These are essentially the same things, however updating allows a user to keep his or her application data between different versions (local data you may have saved that affects the user's personal experience).

The only kind of updates that you can get away with without updating the app are either things controlled via the Google play console OR server side data / synchronised data you may have in the app, however data like your static label is only controlled via the application package and thus must be updated / reinstalled.